# DDE Server Windows:orcascr9.exe: Application Error

Tags: powerbuilder, dde, application-error

I've looked at the queries on SO that pertain to similar errors - but haven't found anything so far, to help with this particular problem I am having with an orcascript which I am running under Powerbuilder9.0. The orca script connects to an SCC service provider, does a full target refresh, and then is supposed to build the exe. It never gets to the last step though.

The log is not very informative and simply says this at the point of failure:
PBORCA_SccRefreshTarget. Full Rebuild 
Calling cm_rebuild_application(CM_REBUILD_FULL) 
While the script is at some way into this above step, it exits and throws up the DDE server error.

Can someone help me figure this one out? I just barely know the basics of PB, and the intent of this exercise is to convert an IDE-based build that I inherited, into an orcascript build so that i can run the build unmonitored.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I am now running Performance monitor per suggestion below, and here is what I see for the orcascr9.exe process at the point of failure.

Class:Filesystem

Operation: QueryAllInformationFile

Result:BUFFER OVERFLOW

Path:c:\.s\00019\MORENUMBERSblah.pbl

Comment: I'm stumped, so I'll ask for clarifications and further tests. When you say "some way into this above step", is it doing an SCC Refresh or the build? Which SCC provider are you using? And, if you try to reproduce these steps in the IDE, are you successful? Jumping ahead, I've found that SysInternals' Process Monitor helps me peek under the covers of a process to see what's going on; sometimes that information is critical in helping solve it.

Comment: By the time it calls cm_rebuild_application it's already pulled everything it needs from source control, so I think the problem lies elsewhere. I'll second Terry's recommendation to fire up Process Monitor and see what's going on.

Are you running the script on the machine you develop on, or are you trying to get it to work on a new build server?

Comment: Hi Terry, yes the IDE build runs fine. No problems there.SCC is clearcase. The script does a succesful "Get latest version", "get connect properties" etc., without a problem. If i check on the time stamps of the libraries while running this scripts, i can see that they are getting updated OK, (multiple cycles of updates in fact). So I dont know at exactly what point the script is thrown off its hinge. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And thanks for the tip about Process Monitor. Have set it up now and will post back if I manage to resolve.

Comment: The QueryAllInformationFile line is probably nothing. There are many Windows functions that you call first with a buffer size of 0 to find out how big a buffer you need. The function returns BUFFER OVERFLOW and sets your parm to the size buffer you need. You'll probably see another call below it that succeeds. Do you see any places where it's trying to open a DLL or EXE and goes through the whole path without finding it? That's not always a problem, it depends on what the program wants the file for. You can search file names in Google to try to determine what they are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I haven't heard a follow up of whether the build is successful in the IDE or not, so I'm going to make suggestions on the assumption that the IDE fails too.

There are a whole series of suggestions that I list at [the Troubleshooting Guide on my site](http://www.techno-kitten.com/PowerBuilder_Help/Troubleshooting/Standard_First_Steps/standard_first_steps.html). In descending order of importance, the ones I'd particularly look at are:

- Optimize all your PBLs (yes, you'll have to do this one PBL at a time unless you've got a tool like [PowerGen](http://www.ecrane.com/PowerGen1.cfm); then again if you've got PowerGen, I wouldn't recommend wasting time on ORCAScript)
- Full Build from within the IDE, making sure Informational messages are turned on (Options menu item from the Library Painter... it used to make sense, but not so much any more); try to address all issues reported
- Look for [multiple versions of your PowerBuilder DLLs](http://www.techno-kitten.com/PowerBuilder_Help/Troubleshooting/Irregular_Behaviour/irregular_behaviour.html) on your system
- Get rid of duplicate objects

If you're still having problems after these steps, there may be other ideas in the Troubleshooting Guide that may inspire some ideas, but I'd be running out of ideas based on the information available to date.

Good luck,

Terry.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to determine the object the build is dying on. One approach is to take a look at the last-modified library. The object the build is dying on will have an older compile date than the build, as will any that the build hadn't gotten to. That may help you narrow things to a few likely suspects. Absent source control I'd suggest shuffling half the non-compiled objects at a time to a different pbl until the build fails on a different pbl. Then you start moving objects from the last batch the other way.  You could copy the pbls and experiment with a regular non-scc build in orcascript but that's a lot of extra work and if the non-scc build works, you'll have a larger mystery instead of a solution.

Comment: that didnt help much -- as ive said in my comment earlier, the timestamps all show up ok, so there is no particular pbl which shows a different timestamp. Thanks though - I'll peg at it some more today and see what comes up.

Comment: Still, inside the libraries you should see objects that didn't get recompiled. I was hoping Terry's PBL Peeper would let you add compile time to the object list, but it doesn't seem to be available.

Comment: Come to think of it, the last library you see accessed in Process Monitor may contain the troublesome object. Have you got any objects that do DDE? I seem to remember PB wants the DDE server when it compiles.